Raffle Sheet to Capture 3 Entries for 3 Ticket Option is NOT Working
I have a Google form where I'm attempting to run a charity raffle. One of the questions is a multiple choice: 1 Raffle Ticket - $20 and the other option is: 3 Raffle Tickets - $50. If someone selects "3 Raffle Tickets" and submits the form, I need 3 corresponding entries in my Google Sheet for the number of tickets they purchased.
I tried using AI to create the Apps Script, but have been unsuccessful. Here is what I currently have:
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  
  var ticketChoice = values[4]; // Assuming ticket choice is in column E
  
  if (ticketChoice.includes("3 Raffle Tickets")) {
    // Add two more rows for 3 Raffle Tickets
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      sheet.appendRow(values);
    }
  }
  // Do nothing for 1 Raffle Ticket as it's already added by form submission
}

I also added a Trigger for this Apps Script:

Choose which function to run: onFormSubmit
Choose which deployment should run: Head
Select event source: From spreadsheet
Select event type: On form submit

In testing the form, here is what's happening. When I select the "3 Raffle Tickets" option, it appears to work:
Test with 3 Raffle Tickets option
However, in my next test I select the "1 Raffle Ticket" option, and here's what happens:
Test with 1 Raffle Ticket option
As you can see, the original entries for 3 tickets is there. However, when I submitted the 1 Rafflet Ticket option, it was added, but 2 other entries were added for the original 3 Ticket entry. Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated so we can launch this charity raffle on time. Thank you!
I'm not a scripting expert, so I tried using Perplexity AI to get a working script (see above), but it's been unsuccessful.
I'm expecting that when someone buys a "3 Raffle Tickets" option, 3 entries are added to the Google Sheet and when someone buys a "1 Raffle Ticket" option, 1 entry is added to the sheet. People can have multiple entries.
UPDATE: I have the script working now and wanted to share it so anyone could benefit from it.
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  try {
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    var ticketColumnIndex = 5;  // Column E = 5
    
    var ticketOption = e.values[ticketColumnIndex - 1].trim();
    Logger.log("Value retrieved from column: " + ticketOption);
    
    var numTickets = parseInt(ticketOption.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
    Logger.log("Number of tickets: " + numTickets);
    
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var rowData = e.values;
    
    // Always add the original entry to the end
    sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
    
    // Add additional entries for multiple tickets
    if (numTickets > 1) {
      for (var i = 1; i < numTickets; i++) {
        lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
        sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
      }
      Logger.log("Entry successfully duplicated " + (numTickets - 1) + " times and grouped at the end.");
    } else {
      Logger.log("Single ticket entry added at the end.");
    }
    
    // Remove the original entry added by the form
    sheet.deleteRow(e.range.getRow());
    
    // Remove any rows with "No Match" in column A
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (values[i][0].toString().startsWith("No Match")) {
        sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
      }
    }
    
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error during form submission processing: " + error);
  }
}


I have the script working now and wanted to share it so anyone could benefit from it. Well done. a better way of sharing it would be to post an answer to your own question. It will close the question, let other users know that there is an answer, and pay it forward to users.

UPDATE: I have the script working now and wanted to share it so anyone could benefit from it.
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  processNewSubmissions();
}

function processNewSubmissions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var ticketColumnIndex = 5;  // Column E = 5
  var processedFlagIndex = 13;  // Column M = 13, we'll use this to mark processed entries
  var timestampIndex = 1;  // Assuming timestamp is in Column A = 1

  Logger.log("Processing submissions on sheet: " + sheet.getName());
  Logger.log("Total rows in sheet (including header): " + data.length);

  var newEntries = [];
  var rowToProcess = null;
  var latestTimestamp = new Date(0);

  // Find the most recent unprocessed submission
  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {  // Start from the bottom, skip header
    var timestamp = new Date(data[i][timestampIndex - 1]);
    var processedFlag = data[i][processedFlagIndex - 1];
    
    Logger.log("Row " + (i + 1) + ": Timestamp=" + timestamp + ", Processed Flag=" + processedFlag);
    
    if (processedFlag !== "Processed" && timestamp > latestTimestamp) {
      rowToProcess = i;
      latestTimestamp = timestamp;
    }
  }

  if (rowToProcess !== null) {
    var ticketOption = data[rowToProcess][ticketColumnIndex - 1].toString().trim();
    Logger.log("Processing submission at row " + (rowToProcess + 1) + ": " + ticketOption);

    var numTickets = 1;  // Default to 1 ticket
    var numMatch = ticketOption.match(/(\d+)/);
    
    if (numMatch) {
      numTickets = parseInt(numMatch[1], 10);
    }
    
    Logger.log("Number of tickets to add: " + numTickets);

    // Add entries for this submission
    for (var j = 0; j < numTickets; j++) {
      var newEntry = data[rowToProcess].slice();  // Create a copy of the row
      if (j === 0) {
        newEntry[processedFlagIndex - 1] = "Processed";  // Mark the first entry as processed
      }
      newEntries.push(newEntry);
      Logger.log("Prepared entry " + (j + 1) + " of " + numTickets + " for " + ticketOption);
    }

    // Add all new entries at once, keeping them grouped
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, newEntries.length, newEntries[0].length).setValues(newEntries);
    Logger.log("Added " + newEntries.length + " new entries to the sheet.");

    // Delete the original unprocessed row
    sheet.deleteRow(rowToProcess + 1);
    Logger.log("Deleted original unprocessed row at position " + (rowToProcess + 1));
  } else {
    Logger.log("No new unprocessed submissions found.");
  }

  // Final check
  var finalRowCount = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;  // Subtract 1 for header row
  Logger.log("Final row count (excluding header): " + finalRowCount);
}

